# Issue with apache pdfbox java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2,Size: 2

Tags: apache, pdfbox

I a using apache pdfbox 1.5 for extracting text from pdf's. Here is the [code](http://www.prasannatech.net/2009/01/convert-pdf-text-parser-java-api-pdfbox.html) which is being used. This seems to work fine for some pdf's. But it failed for one pdf with the below error. Let me know if anyone has encountered such issue & resolved

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2,Size: 2
at java.util.SubList.rangeCheck(AbstractList.java:864)
at java.util.SubList.get(AbstractList.java:737)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.CharStringConverter.drawCurve(CharStringConverter.java:415)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.CharStringConverter.handleType2Command(CharStringConverter.java:277)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.CharStringConverter.handleCommand(CharStringConverter.java:81)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.CharStringHandler.handleSequence(CharStringHandler.java:53)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.CharStringConverter.handleType2Command(CharStringConverter.java:307)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.CharStringConverter.handleCommand(CharStringConverter.java:81)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.CharStringHandler.handleSequence(CharStringHandler.java:53)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.CharStringConverter.convert(CharStringConverter.java:64)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.CFFFont$Mapping.toType1Sequence(CFFFont.java:374)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.AFMFormatter.renderFont(AFMFormatter.java:126)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.AFMFormatter.printFontMetrics(AFMFormatter.java:64)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.AFMFormatter.printFont(AFMFormatter.java:57)
at org.apache.fontbox.cff.AFMFormatter.format(AFMFormatter.java:50)`

Comment: This issue was solved?! I´m stucked in the same point... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to share the PDF file which is creating this issue?

Also, check if the [command line version](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/ExtractText.html) works with the `-force` option enabled.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I have uploaded the pdf [here](http://cid-a3aa7f7d9888874d.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/getting%5E_started%5E_with%5E_Flex3.pdf). Let me know if you are able to extract the text

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to work. I also tried [icePDF](http://www.icepdf.org/) on this file, but that was also not able to extract the text.

Comment: ok, thanks Nikhil for your help! For now I have raised a jira issue with Apache. Lets see what they have to say.